# Recursively copy contents of directory and subdirectories in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

What specific syntax must be used to maintain subdirectory structure while recursively copying the contents of one directory to another directory in PowerShell?

The following command fails to retain the subdirectory structure:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "sourcefoldername" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\\Users\\username\\destinationfoldername\\"
```

Specifically, files located in `sourcefoldername\\subdirectory` get moved by the above command into the `sourcefoldername` directory.  For example, if a source file is located at `sourcefoldername\\subdirectory\\somefile.txt`, the above code makes the mistake of moving the file to `C:\\Users\\username\\destinationfoldername\\somefile.txt` instead of correctly moving the file to `C:\\Users\\username\\destinationfoldername\\subdirectory\\somefile.txt`.

The correct result must move only the contents of `sourcefoldername` and not `sourcefoldername` itself, but must also retain the structure of the subdirectories, with all files remaining in the appropriate subdirectories instead of being moved up to the parent directory as the above code does.

Other examples we have found on the web have either erroneously copied the `sourcefoldername` itself, or have collapsed the contents as above, or have focused on only certain subdirectories, etc.

Comment: See [example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-copy-directory-contents-to-an-existing-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Get-ChildItem` at all

```
Copy-Item -Path \path\to\sourcefoldername\* -Recurse -Destination C:\Users\username\destinationfoldername -Verbose
```

What version of PowerShell are you using?  This is working as expected using PowerShell 7.2.6.  Just tested in PowerShell 5.1 and also working.

```
C:\temp\folder1> tree C:\temp\folder1 /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000
C:\TEMP\FOLDER1
├───subfolder1
│       test1.txt
│
└───subfolder2
        test2.txt

C:\temp\folder1> tree C:\temp\folder2\ /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000
C:\TEMP\FOLDER2
No subfolders exist

C:\temp\folder1> Copy-Item -Path c:\temp\folder1\* -Destination c:\temp\folder2\ -Recurse 

C:\temp\folder1> tree C:\temp\folder2\ /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000
C:\TEMP\FOLDER2
├───subfolder1
│       test1.txt
│
└───subfolder2
        test2.txt
```

Working in GitHub Workflows using windows-latest
[image]

I guess you figured it out.  I'm thinking the issue was probably that your destination folder didn't previously exist?  Seems kind of buggy if the destination folder doesn't exist already.

```
C:\temp> tree C:\temp\folder1\ /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 000000
C:\TEMP\FOLDER1
├───subfolder1
│       test1.txt
│
└───subfolder2
        test2.txt

C:\temp> tree C:\temp\folder2\ /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 000000
C:\TEMP\FOLDER2\
Invalid path - \TEMP\FOLDER2\
No subfolders exist

C:\temp> copy -Path c:\temp\folder1\* -Recurse -Destination c:\temp\folder2
Copy-Item: Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item.

C:\temp> copy -Path c:\temp\folder1\* -Recurse -Destination c:\temp\folder2 -Force

C:\temp> tree C:\temp\folder2\ /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 000000
C:\TEMP\FOLDER2
│   test1.txt
│
├───subfolder1
│       test1.txt
│
└───subfolder2
        test2.txt
```

For some reason test1.txt also gets created in the destination folder when forcing the creation of the folder, but strangely not also test2.txt.

Comment: This is the right answer, I knew it was Example 2 but for some reason OP's comment made me doubt. Seems like they didn't care to read it either.

Comment: Ah, this IS EXACTLY example 2 that you linked to.  Yes, this works.  Not sure why it's not working for CodeMed

Comment: It is working, they didn't care to read it nor try it

Comment: It does only copy the subfolders and contents while retaining the folder structure.  Are you adding the `\*` after the source folder?